# How to append columns

Tags: excel

I was just wondering how to append two columns into one in Excel 2007, with a linebreak.

example:

Before:

```
 ------------------------
 |column1   |     column2|
 -------------------------
```

After:

```
---------
|column1|
|column2|
---------
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: in C1 : `=A1 & CHAR(10) & B1`  Fill down as required. Make sure to turn on text wrapping.

Comment: @TimWilliams worth an answer)))

Comment: Ya...@TimWilliams..that was the solution. Thanks a ton :). If you write an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK then:

In C1 :

```
=A1 & CHAR(10) & B1
```

Fill down as required. 
Make sure to turn on text wrapping.